# Multiplo de un numero que no sea divisor de otro

Tags: c++

Estoy buscando un código que me ayude a regalar bonos de $100.000 a empleados que se encuentren en las posiciones múltiplos de un numero Z ingresado por el usuario, pero que no puede ser divisor de un numero W también ingresado por el usuario, el rango de múltiplos puede ser cualquier valor. El código se debe hacer en c++ y realmente no se como hacer esas dos validaciones :c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;

    cout<<"Multiplos del numero 5"<<endl;
    
    for(x = 5; x <= 100; x += 5){   
        printf("%d\t",x);
    }
}
```

De Momento este es el codigo que tengo con el cual puedo saber lo multiplos de cualquier numero en un rango que yo determino pero no se como pasar esos valores a la condicion de que no sean divisibles entre otro

Comment: Cómo supongo que ya descubriste, hay un operador que te será útil es `%`: te permite obtener el resto/residuo de una división. Por una cuestión matemática, sean **a** y **b** enteros, si **b** es divisor de **a**, el resto de **a/b** es 0. Para rematar, **b** es divisor de **a** sí y solo sí **a** es múltiplo de **b**.

Answer (score 0):

espero que te sirva este código para darte una idea

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
    int numero, i, resto;
    cout << "Este programa muestra todos los divisores de un número" << endl;
    cout << "Dime el multiplo: ";
    cin >> numero;
    cout << "Dime el divisor: ";
    cin >> numero2;
    cout << "Sus divisores son: ";
        for (i=1; i<=numero ; i=i+1)
            {
            resto = numero%i;
            if (resto==0)
                {
              if (i % numero2== 0) {
              cout << i << " ";
              } else {
               return 0;
              }
                
                }
            }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para los que tengan la duda o el mismo inconveniente encontré la solución:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int z, w, i, empleados;
    empleados = 100;
    cout<<"Ingrese el numero Z: ";cin>>z;
    cout<<"Ingrese el numero W: ";cin>>w;

    for(i=z;i <= empleados; i+=z){
        if(i%w == 0){
            cout<<"";
        }else{
            cout<<i<<" ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Como pueden ver en el ejemplo le estoy dando como rango máximo el numero 100 pero esta variable se puede cambiar al antojo, me arrojara todos los múltiplos de Z hasta empleados y que a su vez estos múltiplos no sean divisibles entre w

Comment: El código va como texto.

Comment: el código en formato de código, por favor